# Google Maps markers not displayed in IE7

Tags: jquery, xml, google-maps

I managed to load the map cross-browser but when it comes to populating it with markers, it doesn't work in IE7 (markers are not displayed).
Everything's fine in Firefox.

The locations are stored in XML which is then parsed by javascript and markers are added.

XML structure:

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>    
<stores>
  <store>
    <lat>47.00565</lat> <!-- Note: fake values here -->
    <lng>26.25879</lng>
  </store>
</stores>
```

jQuery code:

```
var loadMarkers = function(xml){
  var $allstores = $(xml).find("store");
  for($i=0; $i<$allstores.length; $i++){
    var $store = $allstores.eq($i);
    var marker= new GMarker(new GLatLng($store.find("lat").text(),$store.find("lng").text()));
    MaCarte.addOverlay(marker);
  }
}
```

It may be useful to know that there are 300+ stores in the XML file.

Did you ever have such a problem?

**UPDATE:**

The problem seems to be on the XML parsing.
Indeed if I alert the number of stores returned like this:

```
alert($allmagasins.length);
```

I get "0" on IE and "252" on Firefox.
Is jQuery not correctly parsing XML in IE?

Comment: Does it work correct when you put static coords instead of `$store.find("lat").text()` ?

Comment: Can you show how you load the XML before calling loadMarkers?

Comment: The xml variable is just a string built in PHP.

Comment: Think it's due to IEs poor implementation of loading images on runtime. My tip would be to use the marker manager. Not only to solve this problem, but it's rather intense on the CPU to use addOverlay in every loop. 

The Marker manager can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-dev/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found the solution.

When dealing with IE and XML parsing with jQuery, some stuff has to be done in order to make it work.

Here's my updated working jQuery code:

```
var loadMarkers = function(xml){

  if($.browser.msie){
    var data = xml;
    xml = new ActiveXObject( 'Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    xml.async = false;
    xml.loadXML(data);
  }

  var $allstores = $(xml).find("store");
  for($i=0; $i<$allstores.length; $i++){
    var $store = $allstores.eq($i);
    var marker= new GMarker(new GLatLng($store.find("lat").text(),$store.find("lng").text()));
    MaCarte.addOverlay(marker);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pasted the wrong link in my comment. 
http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/

Here's an example (untested)

```
var markerManager = new MarkerManager(map)
markerManager.addMarker(marker)
markerManager.refresh();
```

..fredrik